# Element type is invalid: expected a string with FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

Iam new to react-native, and are playing around with UI Kitten (https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/)
It has a default ChatListScreenBase that renders a list. It looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ListView
} from 'react-native';


import ThemeService from '../util/ThemeService';
import api from '../util/ApiMock';

export default class ChatListScreenBase extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
    });
    let data = api.getUserMsgList(api.userId);

    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data)
    };
  }

  render() {
     let Header = ThemeService.getChatListHeaderComponent();
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header/>
        <ListView
          style={styles.list}
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(row) => this._renderMsgItem(row)}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

  _renderMsgItem(msg) {
    let user = api.getUserInfo(msg.from);
    let ChatItem = ThemeService.getChatItemComponent();
    msg.text = msg.text.length > 25 ? msg.text.substring(0,23)+'...' : msg.text;
    return (
      <ChatItem
        user={user}
        message={msg}
        onClick={(user) => this._openChat(user)}
      />
    );
  }

  _openChat(user) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      screen: ThemeService.getChatScreen(true),
      passProps: {
        userId: user.id
      }
    });
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
  },
  list: {
    paddingTop: 10
  },
});
```

I would like to substitute the data this screen renders, with my own code, like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';

import ajax from '../util/ApiMock';

export class ChatListScreenBase extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      themeIndex: ThemeService.getCurrentThemeIndex()
    }
  }

  state = {
    data: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await ajax.getDataTest();
    this.setState({data});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} >
        <Text style={styles.h2text}>
          Black Order
        </Text>
          <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={({item}) =>
          <View style={styles.flatview}>
            <Text style={styles.name}>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
          }
          keyExtractor={item => item.title}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  h2text: {
    marginTop: 10,
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    fontSize: 36,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  flatview: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 30,
    borderRadius: 2,
  },
  name: {
    fontFamily: 'Verdana',
    fontSize: 18
  },
  email: {
    color: 'red'
  }
});
```

When I do this, I keep getting this error:

"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `ChatListScreenBase`."

I think that the problem is with the `<FlatList>`, but I'am not sure what type its expecting?

When I call the webservice it returns:

> {"users":[{"_id":"5d0fcd8fe1dbfd7c23424e09","title":"180710","type":1,"published":"5"},{"_id":"5d0fcd8fe1dbfd7c23424e0a","title":"180705","type":3,"publiched":"5"},{"_id":"5d0fcd8fe1dbfd7c23424e0b","title":"Mr.
>   Nick","type":2,"publiched":"5"}]}

Kind regards.

Comment: it means `title` key is not present in your data, can you verify that title is indded coming ?

Comment: It should be returned. I just updaed the question with the actual response from the webserver.

Comment: looks like your api response is returning data which is of type object which has key users what is what you want to render. can you double chech your data you are setting in state, it should be `const data = await ajax.getDataTest();
    this.setState({data: data.users});`

Comment: nice, I have posted it as answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the looks of your API response you are setting `data` as object with key users and then trying to loop over it.

Instead update componentDidmount:

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    const resp = await ajax.getDataTest();
    this.setState({ data: resp.users });
  }
```